# How can I copy data from a database table into a textfile using Delphi?

Tags: delphi, ms-access, copy, delphi-7

I am trying to copy data from `tblDeelnemers` of `dbDeelnemers` into textfile `Deelnemers.txt`

The table contains 4 columns namely: ID, Naam, van, kontaknommer.
I have a **TADOQuery** on my form as well as a **dbGrid**. I am using **Microsoft Access** and **Delphi 7**.

I have search for possible ways but the only help i can get is for C#.

I Want to recall this Textfile later when a button is clicked. The format of the saved data doesn't matter I just need to be able to load it back into a dataset. I am doing it this way because after this "import" the data from the table is deleted to start from the beginning

I tried the following but it is completely wrong:

```
var
 sDeelnemers : string;//string to copy data in before adding to textfile
Begin // sIDkies is global string
    frmData.qryVGKompetisieDB.Active := false;   
    frmData.qryVGKompetisieDB.SQL.Text := 'copy ID, Naam, Van, Kontaknommer from tblDeelnemers into sDeelnemers WHERE ID = "'+sIDkies+'"; // copying data into string
    frmData.qryVGKompetisieDB.ExecSQL;
    frmData.qryVGKompetisieDB.SQL.Text := 'Select * from tblDeelnemers'; // to show table on dgGrid like originally
    frmData.qryVGKompetisieDB.Active := true;
end; // then assigning textfile and copying sDeelnemers(string) into textfile
```

Thanks to @No'am Newman the code is now as followed:

```
procedure TfrmData.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  f: tstrings;
  q: TADOQuery;
begin
  redInfo.Visible := false;
  dbgInfo.Visible := true;
  qryVGKompetisieDB.Active := false;
  qryVGKompetisieDB.SQL.Text := 'select id, naam, van, Kontaknommer from tblDeelnemers';
  qryVGKompetisieDB.ExecSQL;
  qryVGKompetisieDB.Active := true;

  f:= tstringlist.create;
 with q do
  begin
   open;    //Error occurs here 
   while not eof do
    begin
     f.add (fieldbyname ('id').asstring + ',' +
            fieldbyname ('naam').asstring + ',' +
            fieldbyname ('Van').asstring + ',' +
            fieldbyname ('Kontaknommer').asstring);
     next
    end;
   close
  end;

 f.savetofile ('Deelnemers.txt');
 f.free
end;
```

But now I am getting the following error when the TADOQuery is opened (As indicated in the code):

> Project PAT_p.exe raised exception class EAccessViolation with message 'Access Violation at address 004A990C in module 'PAT_p.exe'. Read of address 8BD88CCB'. Process stopped. Use Step or Run to continue.

Comment: Your comment on the local variable is correct, but your 5th line looks very random. Even if `COPY` DML statement would be present in the Access SQL interpreter, it would a) manipulate whole rowset b) would not know about local(!) variable.

Comment: You mentioned you are using TQuery (with the outdated BDE)? If you would use TADO(Query)Dataset you could save and load the data in a binary or XML format (pfAdtg,pfXML) via Dataset.SaveToFile / LoadFromFile.

Comment: Please do not add more details to your question to expect a different answer. You need to ask a new question - as this is an entirely different issue. However it points right out to me that you did not create your query `q := TADOQuery.Create(nil);` Not only that, but you didn't even specify a SQL statement for `q`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can iterate over the returned set and write each row into a text file. Your query appears to be

```
select id, naam, van, Kontaknommer
from tblDeelnemers
```

Here is some basic code to extract the values from all the rows in the table and write them to a text file (actually, a csv file - you can choose your separator).

```
var
 f: tstrings;
 q: tquery; // whichever type you use

begin
 f:= tstringlist.create;
 with q do
  begin
   open;
   while not eof do
    begin
     f.add (fieldbyname ('id').asstring + ',' +  
            fieldbyname ('naam').asstring + ',' +
            fieldbyname ('Van').asstring + ',' +
            fieldbyname ('Kontaknommer').asstring);
     next
    end;
   close
  end;

 f.savetofile ('Deelnemers.txt');
 f.free
end;
```

It would be quicker to use permanent fields (ie qID.asstring, etc) rather than using 'fieldbyname' all the time. Also, you should put some error checking around the creation of the stringlist.

Comment: But this doesn't help the OP when it comes to loading the data back up.

Comment: @JerryDodge: I admit that I didn't see the bit of the question that referred to loading the table afterwards. See my comment to your answer.

Comment: @No'am Newman I am now getting the following error when the TADOQuery is opened (As indicated in the code):

**Project PAT_p.exe raised exception class EAccessViolation with message 'Access Violation at address 004A990C in module 'PAT_p.exe'. Read of address 8BD88CCB'. Process stopped. Use Step or Run to continue.**

Comment: @sgtBlueBird When you asked this question, I made sure to find out from you if you intend to load this data back up. As I mentioned in my comment on this answer, this solution does not allow you to load this data back up. Please take a look at the answer which I provided. Especially for as unfamiliar as you are with Delphi, this solution is WAY over your head (even if you could load it back up).

Comment: @Jerry Dodge I did say "...is opened (As indicated in the code).." any how it is on the **open;** part where the TADOQuery is opened.;

Comment: @sgtBlueBird Please refer to my comment on your question above, where I point out the query component hasn't been created.

Comment: @Jerry Dodge I will try to create it now. I do not need to load the data back into a table only into say a richedit (redInfo)

Comment: @JerryDodge @No'am Newman Thanks for your help i only added the following like Jerry suggested: `q := TADOQuery.Create(nil);` and 
  `q.ConnectionString := 'Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=D:\flash IT 2\VGLKdb.mdb;Persist Security Info=True';` and 
  `q.SQL.Text := 'select id, naam, van, Kontaknommer from tblDeelnemers';`

Answer (score 1):

What you are looking for is a [`ClientDataSet`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE2/en/Datasnap.DBClient.TClientDataSet) which has the ability to `SaveToFile` and `LoadFromFile`. You would need to use this in coordination with what you might already have - meaning you need to populate your data into this dataset and then save it from there.

Keep in mind that this requires the use of `Midas.dll`. I know later versions of Delphi have an option whether or not to require it, but not sure if that was an option in Delphi 7.

Comment: I'm fairly sure that all versions had this - add `MidasLib` to the uses section of the project DPR

Comment: @JerryDodge: I use Delphi 7 - the clientdataset component has both 'savetofile' and 'loadfromfile' methods, so this would indeed seem to be the easiest way to achieve the user's request. MidasLib doesn't have to be added as a unit, as long as the midas.dll file is located in the same directory as the final program. This is useful if several programs are going to be using the same dll.

Comment: Yes, this is optional - If you include `MidasLib` then you don't need the DLL, if you don't include `MidasLib` then you do need the DLL - which the DLL can also go into your system folder. Either way, regardless of this option, the concept is the same.